# Is there a setting to blank the screen when the on/off switch is pressed for lockscreen?

Tags: settings, lock-screens, power-on

I"m running Android 10, and I've not had this problem/issue with the lock screen on any previous iterations of the OS.

### The problem

In the past, When the on/off switch is pressed, this enables lockscreen and the system goes into a wait state. The screen blanks and stops monitoring gestures or taps. It needs the on/off switch or the finger recognition scanner to come back on.

### What I'm looking for

A setting that will switch the screen off until I hit the on/off switch, preferable not the finger scanner

Comment: I think you are trying to disable double tap to open...? You can disable it in Gestures/Moves in the settings.

Comment: No, Double tap is resolved. The Accessibility problem arose because I put my hand in the laptop bag in the front pocket (where stuff is kept) and touched the finger scanner. Because the screen remains active during lockscreen, it switched on and then (as chance happens) bounced about  unseen until it hit talkbalk. I've had every iteration of android since that first Motorola (remember that one? with the sliding keyboard?) and the most recent was the Nexus 5X. All of them blanked the screen when the off button was depressed. Problem is as stated.

Comment: This issue pre-dates the TalkBack. Having an 'active' screen means that whenever the phone is bumped (in the pocket, laptop bag etc) it momentarily responds with an unlock screen, this drains battery, and can't be good for the phone. The inadvertant  finger scan is an escalation of all this, of course.

Comment: Resolved after a factory reinstall